# Disable jump to file on ctrl+click at reference identifier

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to disable jumping to another file, which occurs when clicking on reference identifier (for example library method or module element) with `CTRL` key pressed down?

I'm often using mouse select with `ctrl+c/ctrl+v` and IDEA often mistakes this operation with jump operation.

Comment: Yes, hold down `shift` as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Keymap*
2. In the Keymap, go to *Main Menu > Navigate > Declaration*
3. Right click the `Declaration` entry and select "remove Ctrl+Button1 Click"

   - Note, if you are using a Default kymap, you will need to first copy (at the top) the keymap before you can edit it. You can only edit custom keymaps.
4. Click OK